# Wrapping sencha touch with Phonegap in eclipse for android

Tags: eclipse, cordova, sencha-touch

I found sencha touch interesting andafter trying a default app in web, wanted to do some app for mobile devices.  I was trying to wrap sencha touch with phonegap in eclipse for android by following the steps as mentioned in (this link) http://bgmemo.com/tutorial-sencha-touch-and-phonegap/. But as soon as i launch emulator a white screen with name android appears and within seconds i get error as "The Requested file was not found./android_asset/www/index.html(no such file directory) (file:///android_asset//www//index.html)". I am not getting errors in console. Any solutions plz?

1)I have already tried (this)http://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/

Answer (score 0):

The entire Sencha touch project should be in www folder. Then the application will be launched. You can write script to compile your sencha touch project and then copy the project contents to www.

The directory 'www' is the entry for the hybrid applicatoin. Try this and let me know.